# How to PyCharm import inside a class is actually used?

Tags: pycharm, python-import

While using the following pattern:

```
class A(object):
    from my_methods import a_method as a
    from my_methods import b_method as b
```

I encountered a problem: PyCharm considers those methods as unused and Optimize imports remove them.

One way to mark methods as used is to mention them in a class, for example:

```
class A(object):
    from my_methods import a_method as a
    from my_methods import b_method as b
    a, b
```

But then PyCharm complains about this line is having no effect.

Is there the right way to solve the problem? Maybe some hints or pragmas?

The methods are used indirectly, so PyCharm can't deduce their usage (there are no direct `A().a()` calls in the code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you ever call the methods?

**my_methods.py**

```py
def a_method(self):
    pass

def b_method(self):
    pass
```

**optimize.py**

```py
class A(object):
    from my_methods import a_method as a
    from my_methods import b_method as b

def _unused():
    x = A()
    x.a()
    x.b()
```

When I ran `[Code]->[Optimize Imports]` on `optimize.py`, the imports were not removed.

The `_unused` can be also a method of the class `A`, and may serve for tests and documentation.

Comment: Yes, they are called. However, they are not called directly: The use case is a mini-framework, PyCharm can't deduce those methods are called. Amended my question.

Comment: Maybe just add a function that creates and object and calls the methods, but never call the function?

Comment: Unfortunately, that spoils the whole idea of minimal declarations I am trying to achieve. The alternative is to have a Mixin, but I want to see if this style is more concise...

Comment: I tried to add a function under tests, but it had no effect.

Comment: Unless someone comes with PyCharm way, I could accept you answer with the following amendment: I can add `_selftest` method, which calls those "mixed-in" methods. This has the same effect as standalone function, but no need to init the class. Plus it provides documentation (a kin to doctest) and simplifies unit-tests. However, PyCharm does not understand `self` disappears and complain about wrong number of parameters, but I can probably live with it. Thanks!

Comment: You should probably self-answer or edit my answer. I'm not sure I understand your problem well enough to claim to be able to solve it. You would have to add a lot more information to your question for me to understand what you are trying to achieve.